# CMake Error for a OpenCV/CUDA project due to lost CUDAConfig.cmake

Tags: linux, cmake, cuda, nvidia

I have been trying to install and uninstall CUDA a few time to address the problem that it seems to be inconsistent to what information I can find online. For example inside my `/usr/local/cuda/bin/` I lack an uninstall script which I think should be there given my 12.2 installation. Worse yet I cannot seem to correct my CMake and have exhausted most methods found on forums. I will attach all relevant information below.

**Platform**

- HP Omen 15
- Linux Ubuntu 22.04
- GeForce RTX 2070
- NVIDIA-SMI 535.54.03 - Driver Version: 535.54.03
- CUDA Version: 12.2

**`CMakeLists.txt`**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(synchronisation_buffer)

# Set C++ Standards
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# FIND LIBRARIES
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${CUDA_LIBS}")

# INCLUDE HEADERS
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# Target the only executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/main.cpp 
    src/main.hpp 
    src/buffer.hpp 
)
```

**Inside `.bashrc`**

```bash
# CUDA Bash links
# export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}$ 
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/lib
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/include
```

**Inside `usr/local`**

```
XXXX@XXXX-OMEN-Laptop-15-ek0xxx:/usr/local$ ls
bin cuda cuda-12 cuda-12.2 doc etc games include lib man sbin share src
```

**Inside `cuda/bin`**

```
XXXX@XXXX-OMEN-Laptop-15-ek0xxx:/usr/local/cuda/bin$ ls
bin2c cudafe++ cuobjdump nsight_ee_plugins_manage.sh nsys-ui nvdisasm nvvp
computeprof cuda-gdb fatbinary nsight-sys nvcc nvlink ptxas
compute-sanitizer cuda-gdbserver ncu nsys __nvcc_device_query nvprof
crt cu++filt ncu-ui nsys-exporter nvcc.profile nvprune
```

**ERROR**

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake:86 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindCUDA.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "CUDA", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CUDA" (requested
  version 12.2) with any of the following names:

    CUDAConfig.cmake
    cuda-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "CUDA" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "CUDA_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "CUDA"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake:108 (find_host_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html — the missing CMake module is not part of the CUDA toolkit, it is part of CMake, and since first class language support was added for CUDA, deprecated and now removed from new CMake builds. You either need to modify the build files for you project or use an older version of CMake

Comment: Changing the cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27) fixed the issue immediately thank you for that @talonmies, I couldn't find anyone suggesting this across similar quires and would never have known it to be a deprecation issue without someone identifying it.

Comment: Please write a short answer explaining what you did to fix the problem for the next person who has the same issue.

Comment: If you used the Runfile to install CUDA and there is no `cuda-12.0/bin/cuda-uninstaller`, you might want to file a bug, as it is [explicitly documented](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#uninstallation). If you used your system package manager to install it, I would not expect it to exist.

Answer (score 1):

As per @talonmies comment, due to 3.27 deprecation it is no longer necessary to use this module or call `find_package(CUDA)` for compiling CUDA code (for linking CUDA libraries use the newer `find_package(CUDAToolkit)`). To resolve the issue in my OP, I simply reduced the `cmake_minimum_required()` to anything before the 3.27 release i.e. 3.26 and below.

Links Referencing relevant info:

- [deprecated `FindCUDA` CMake Module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html)
- [new `FindCUDAToolkit` CMake Module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDAToolkit.html)
- [CMake Release Notes 3.X](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/index.html)

Comment: I think this answer would be better (more future-proof), if you would leave `cmake_minimum_required()` at 3.27 and use the new CMake features to fix your problem.